# including external URL javascript file

Tags: javascript, jsp, asp-classic

I have a main header page that is included in many different applications across a couple of different languages, including Java and classic ASP. The file (file.js) is going to be obsolete soon. We are going to be going to an "out-of-the-box" solution, a new header created by another group. They gave us a link ("google.com") that we need to use to show this new header. I was wondering if there was a simple solution I could implement in my file.js that would show this content to the users. I know an easy way to do it in jsp is
`<c:import url="http://google.com"/>`

but this won't work in the js file, nor will it work in the jsp. Is there a way for me to do this?

Thank you,
Explosive_donut

Comment: What do you mean by _show this content to the users_? Link the URL from within the JS?

Comment: I mean that I want to display the content of the webpage (google.com) to the users as the header, that way the header will be google.com

Comment: Header as website header in a `div` or document header?

Comment: Header as website header in a div. Sorry for not being clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the URL you are really given isn't Google. I suppose the second team is able to modify their own (document) headers sent to clients.

First way I think of is to use AJAX to retrieve the contents of the URL and create a `div` or select an existing to set its new content.

Unfortunately AJAX is restricted to the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) which can be circumvented with [CORS (Cross Origin Resource Sharing)](http://enable-cors.org/). To allow CORS, your remote server as well as your client maschines need to send respective headers. Check out the link for more information.

If you need any more information and/or tutorials, let me know in the comments.

Comment: Thanks I'll check this out. If it works, I will let you know.